# Is a not injectable service still a service or is it better to use something different?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I found so many different answers to this problem and I'm always looking for best practices.

I have created a service of which I need multiple instances. This services takes some data as an input and creates a csv out of it.

Well I tried this with a very standard injectable service.

```
@Injectable
export class ExportCsv {
  public constructor(Data: any) {
    // Do something and spit out csv
  }
}
```

The problem is, if I provide this in my component, the data is obviously not reset and basically just appended since there is only one instance of my service. So, if this component creates multiple csv, every csv will have some data which shouldn't be there.

I found some solutions:
- Create some kind of factory
- Make the service not injectable and don't provide it. So it will be handled like a standard class and every time I use it I have to crate an instance of this class (new ExportCsv)
- Just don't call it a service and basically do the same with it as with the "not injectable" service

Is there some kind of best practice to my problem?
Is a service which won't be provided via the providers and is not injectable really still a service?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the term Service means to "serve something".. Like serving data from a DB, serving User related stuff or even provided methods for changing data can be looked at as a Service. The Problem in your case is that the static instance of the DI Service will always hold up the data that you've previously provided to it.

So technically speaking if you have the possibility to keep the data inside a collection like a Map instead of the Service Class itself, then you could provide an injectable service that holds a map with given keys that will hold the data of your csvs.

If that's not the case then I would suggest to the quote from your post above for the best practice case :

> So it will be handled like a standard class and every time I use it I have to crate an instance of this class (new ExportCsv)

So basically you could either make a collection or create a new class for this functionality and save the object to a collection inside of your injectable service.

Regards